# Should Hadoop be restarted if core-site.xml is updated

Tags: hadoop2

I am a newbie of Hadoop, I added more properties to core-site.xml in currently running Hadoop system, so should I restarted Hadoop to make those new properties available

Answer (score 3):

The `core-site.xml` file tells Hadoop daemon where `NameNode` is running in the cluster. It contains the configuration that overrides default settings for Hadoop Core such as I/O settings that are common to `HDFS`.

You can reload configuration without cluster restart. Check `dfsadmin`

```
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNamenodes datanodehost:port
```

For the given datanode, reloads the configuration files, stops serving the removed block-pools and starts serving new block-pools.

See [HDFS Command Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) how to reload configuration?

Comment: I think you can do this using dfsadmin -refreshNamenodes option. check

Comment: `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes` will also do this for all nodes without needing to know host:port information.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh all the Namenodes, you can use

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/refresh-namenodes.sh
```